# ActiveRecord references index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I was just wondering why is it important for a table with column that references to other table (models associated to other models) be indexed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: because it can improve the speed of joins...

Answer (score 2):

It may help you to understand "Why Indexed" .

http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/Indexes/What-are-best-practices-to-pick-columns-to-index

http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/Indexes/What-are-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-indexes-in-MySQL